# CSS Inline Image border keeps stepping down

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble trying to set two graphic borders properly, a left and right border. This is contained inside a body along with a  text area. My goal is to "sandwich" this in the following order: left border gfx, text area, right border gfx. But I'm running into two problems. The left border is not stretching to match the variable height of my text area, and the right border is stepping down off from what looks like the body div or text div.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        header

        <div id="logo"></div>

        <div id="title&quot;"></div>

        <div id="login"></div>
    </div><!--END HEADER-->

    <div id="menu">
        menu
    </div>

    <div id="body">
        <div id="shadeL">
            <!--not formatting height properly-->
            &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div id="text">
            Body Contentadsfasdf
        </div>

        <div id="shadeR">
            <!--stepping down off from body or text div-->
            &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div><!--END BODY-->

    <div id="footer">
        footer - 2015
    </div>
</div><!--END WRAPPER-->
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {}

#shadeL {
    background-image:url(../ILshadow.jpg);
    width:22px;
    height:inherit;
    display:inline;
    background-repeat:repeat-y
}

#shadeR {
    clear:right;
    float:right;
    background-image:url(../IRshadow.jpg);
    width:22px;
    background-repeat:repeat-y
}

#header {
    background-image:url(../header.jpg);
    width:1024px;
    height:56px
}

#menu {
    background-image:url(../menu.jpg);
    width:1024px;
    height:31px
}

#body {
    background-color:#e0e0e0;
    width:1024px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:8px
}

#text {
    display:inline;
    width:700px;
    margin-left:40px
}

#footer {
    background-image:url(../footer.jpg);
    width:1024px;
    height:39px
}
```

*Edit: 
https://jsfiddle.net/hnftp346/ 
Sorry folks here is the jsfiddle, although Im still trying to figure out how to upload gfx to the site

Comment: give us a fiddle link of the code. Can't reproduce what you are asking for with the code provided

Comment: Put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry https://jsfiddle.net/hnftp346/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not mistaken you are looking for something like this, no?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/n1kz39ex/)

```css
.row {
  display: table;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.header {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.left {
  background-color: blue;
}
.right {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12 header'>Header</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-1 left'></div>
    <div class='col-xs-10'>This is my main content
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>t t t</div>
    <div class='col-xs-1 right'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, however, I was having a strange issue where if I would view the html doc locally everything would render correctly. But if I would view it on my websever, it would not. I ended up not using these boarders and used other formatting. Using IE 9 for anyone thats curious.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `width` of all elements and start use `float`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvcxwhk4/)

`background-color` was set, because I dont know what is url with Your graphics.

You can remove it.